# Manually deleting \chapter ruins all hyperlinks in the document

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, hyperref, appendices

I'm a tex noob and I'm using doxygen to generate a pdf documentation.
I had doxygen generate a refman.tex file which contains something like

```
\chapter{Program Reference}
\label{index}\hypertarget{index}{}\input{index}
\chapter{Appendix}
\label{_appendix}
\hypertarget{_appendix}{}
\input{_appendix}
\chapter{Useless chapter}
...
\chapter{Module Index}
...
```

I'd like to

1) Move Appendix at the end of the document
2) Delete the Useless chapter

Since I can't get doxygen to generate a latex as I want, I edited the main refman.tex file by hand and moved Appendix at the end and deleted the useless chapter.

Turns out the document has the structure I want but the hyperlinks of the last sections are all ruined and point to the document's beginning

What am I doing wrong? How are hyperlinks created between sections of a tex document?

Comment: Have you tried a rerun? The table of contents information is written to the `.toc` file and the PDF bookmarks are written to the `.out` file. If you modify the sectioning structure these will be out of date and a rerun is needed.

Comment: What is a re-run? I'm using MikTex to re-generate the pdf

Comment: A re-run is re-generating the PDF. If that doesn't work you need to provide a proper [minimal example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/) that includes the `\documentclass` line and the `document` environment.

Comment: delete all the auxillary files.  that can solve things

Comment: We haven't heard back, deleting the aux file might be all that is needed to solve the question. Well, with the information at hand, unclear. VtC